# Arbitrary GOP structure in HM reference software

Tags: hevc

I am using trying to setup an arbitrary GOP structure (a GOP structure other than hierarchical B or IPPP...) in HM-16.3. I fiddled around with the configuration file setting up the GOP pattern. However, I do not know how I can force the encoder to choose a particular reference frame from a list of reference frames in the reference picture set. Is this even possible in the reference encoder?

Comment: What is unclear in this question that it was down voted?

Comment: As far as I can see, you can only specify a relative position for the reference frames in the config file. (In the reference pictures "column". as an example -2 -6 2 6 for a B-frame)

Comment: @damjeux: yeah you are right, you can only specify the reference frames that the current and any future frames will use. However,  you cannot specify which among the reference frames the encoder should choose as reference. That said, I have found that by using/(abusing) the RPS prediction listing of the GOP description in the config file, you can force the encoder to choose any particular frame as a reference frame for the current picture.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to change the GOP structure of the HM without manipulating the source code and only with the config parameters. 
You are right, it's way too complicated.

I can explain it here but surely I can not explain it as good as the way it is explained in the reference manual. 
And it seems that you've just done it with trial and error.

Take a look at [this](https://jvet.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HMJEMSoftware/tags/HM-14.0-KTA-2.0/doc/software-manual.pdf) manual at page 3.

Also [this](https://jvet.hhi.fraunhofer.de/svn/svn_HMJEMSoftware/tags/HM-14.0-KTA-2.0/doc/gop-structure-example.pdf) is an example of how it works:

Comment: Is it possible to define an odd number for `GOPSize`? Because I get the error `GOP Size must be a multiple of 2, if GOP Size is greater than 1`.

Comment: OK, thank you! Do you have any idea how to define the GOP structure for GOPSize=96? I mean the parameters that I have to set.